# UISearchBar not displaying correct tintColor

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

If i add my UISearchBar without referencing it to a UISearchDisplayController, my tintColor is displayed correctly.

[image: UISearchBar with correct tintColor]

```
searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:21.0f/255.0f blue:26.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

But if i reference my UISearchBar to a UISearchDisplayController the color seems different...

[image: UISearchBar referenced to a UISearchDisplayController with wrong tintColor]

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[searchBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:21.0f/255.0f blue:26.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleProminent;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Buscar restaurantes o platillos";
searchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.delegate = self;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

My tintColor settings on my AppDelegate are

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:21.0f/255.0f blue:26.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:21.0f/255.0f blue:26.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:21.0f/255.0f blue:26.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Besides that also when my UISearchBar is referenced to my UISearchDisplayController and i tap on the search field... on the transition the background of the Status bar is white.

[image: Transition UISearchBar on a UISearchDisplayController]

Any ideas?

i'm Using iOS7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set image in searcher. It will work for searchbar.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red"]];
```

Comment: it worked great, now i'm just trying to find a way to show the same color in the background for the transition.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the translucent property to no.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution working on iOS7+

```
searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
searchBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.Normal
searchBar.barTintColor = Utils.tintColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

For **UISearchController** in **Swift** use:

```
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```